# How to implement a Int128 type under Delphi?

Tags: delphi

When I look the source code of delphi I can see :

```
unit System
// Result := Int64((Int128(AValue) * Int128(AMul)) div ADiv);
```

so is their any plan to support soon int128 under delphi? Else what is the best type I can use to store 128-bit number?

for example :

```
  Int128 = record
    high,low : Int64;
  end align 16;
```

But how to convert this record to printable a number like '548852636555'?

Comment: Why do you need 128-bit numbers?

Comment: Personally, I'd like that for simple number theory work.

Comment: I don't think Embarcadero is planning this, but of course you are free to implement your own such type. With operator overloading, it can be made to behave exactly like the built-in integer types.

Comment: Why don't you use a big number library? Like this: https://github.com/rvelthuis/DelphiBigNumbers

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes I will use it, it's very sad that the author passed away :(